# Check if float contains decimal with 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am generating a random floating value between 1.00 and 5.00. Sometimes the value comes as 1.08 or 3.09. I do not wish to have this, instead it should be 1.00 or 3.00 when it comes to such a case. That is whenever there is a decimal with 0 soon after, the value should always be .00.

Such that if X.0Y is a value, the final value should be X.00.

Example: value = 3.08;
output final value = 3.00

```
public float selectedValueRange;

void Start(){
  selectedValueRange = Random.Range (1.0, 5.0+ 1.0f);
  selectedValueRange = Mathf.Round (selectedValueRange * 100.0f) * 0.01f;
}
```

Comment: Then why not generate random integers instead?

Comment: well other cases i do need floating values. It is not that I am only using integers :D

Comment: We're not talking about other cases, we're talking about this case. And you can generate a random int, but cast it to a float if you need to.

Comment: the thing is i want to continue it this way because I want the number to be generated as float with 2 decimal points as I am doing. All I want is if there is .0 in a case, then I want it to replace it to .00. That is all I want.

Comment: I cannot change the structure from int to float as of now.

Comment: But `1.0` is the same as `1.00`, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Are you saying that X.0Y should be rounded down to X.0 while anything else should be left as is?

Comment: yes. Only when the condition is X.0Y, then the final value should be X.00. While the rest stays as float with 2 values after decimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get rid of everything after the decimal point and then check if the difference between the new value and the previous number is less than `0.1f` which means your number is in this format `x.0y`. If it is then reassign the new value as the random value. Something like the following code:

```
int number = (int)selectedValueRange;
if(selectedValueRange-number < 0.1f){
   selectedValueRange = (float)number;
}
```